# what is the meaning of select ''-''

Tags: mysql, sql

There is an article about SQL injection: [**Abusing MySQL string arithmetic for tiny SQL injections**](http://blog.kotowicz.net/2013/01/abusing-mysql-string-arithmetic-for.html)

The question is, what is the meaning of `select ''-''` ? I try it with MySQL, and it returns:

```
mysql> select ''-'';
+-------+
| ''-'' |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What happend?  What means that 0?

And the result of `select '-'`:

```
mysql> select '-';
+---+
| - |
+---+
| - |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am very confused about these result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are minus `-` from one empty string `''` to other:

See following:

```
mysql> select '';
+--+
|  |
+--+
|  |
+--+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)  

mysql> select '3'-'2';
+---------+
| '3'-'2' |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But warning if its not *a number string*:

```
mysql> select 'a'-'b';
+---------+
| 'a'-'b' |
+---------+
|       0 |
+---------+
1 row in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Two warnings:

```
mysql> SHOW WARNINGS LIMIT 2
    -> ;
+---------+------+---------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                               |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'a' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'b' |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

*Why no warning for `empty` string?*

Where as there is no warning for empty string because its(casted something) `0` see below:

```
mysql> SELECT 0 = '';
+--------+
| 0 = '' |
+--------+
|      1 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

hence by doing `''-''` you are doing `0 - 0`

```
mysql> SELECT '' - '';
+---------+
| '' - '' |
+---------+
|       0 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

To be more clear I am adding following example (*I feels will be helpful to you*):
How conversion happen:

```
mysql> SELECT '0' = 0
    -> ;
+---------+
| '0' = 0 |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

notice its conversion:

```
mysql> SELECT '' = '0'
    -> ;
+----------+
| '' = '0' |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

`''` converted into `0`, `'0'` converted into `0` but `''` not equals to `'0'`

```
mysql> SELECT '1' = 1
    -> ;
+---------+
| '1' = 1 |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT '' = 1
    -> ;
+--------+
| '' = 1 |
+--------+
|      0 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd explain `select ''-''`, which is the same as `select '' - ''`, as `select cast('' as int) -  cast('' as int)` which is `select 0-0`..

With `select '-'` you just get a string. Hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

`''` is an empty string; `-` is subtraction. So you're subtracting one empty string from another. Subtraction is a numeric operator, so its result is a number, and mysql converts its arguments into numbers before subtracting them. The numeric value of `''` is zero — but it doesn't matter very much, since any number subtracted from itself is going to give zero anyway.