# MySQL automatically cast/convert a string to a number?

Tags: mysql, type-conversion, casing

Does MySQL automatically casting\converting the string to numeric value?
How does that conversion works?

- '1234'=1234 ?
- '1abc' = 1 ?
- 'text' = 1 ?

Given that `units.id` is of bigint type, how this query will be interpreted?

```
SELECT table.* 
FROM table 
WHERE id='text'
```

Comment: [yes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411380/what-is-the-meaning-of-select/14411466#14411466)

Comment: Note that this is another good reason to validate any user-supplied parameters before using them in a query (even when using prepared statements).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answers to your first three questions are:  yes, yes, and no.

When the string `'text'` is converted to a number, it becomes the value `0`.

The documentation that describes type conversion is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html).

For your query:

```
SELECT table.* 
FROM table 
WHERE id='text';
```

The rule is captured by this excerpt from the documentation:

> In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers.

In other words, this is actually equivalent to:

```
WHERE id = 0.0
```

Answer (score 5):

MySQL by default treats 1 and '1' the same however you can change that by setting the MySQL behavior to Strict mode.

```
set @@GLOBAL.sql_mode  = "STRICT_ALL_TABLES";
set @@SESSION.sql_mode = "STRICT_ALL_TABLES";
```

or you can set these variables in your my.cnf file to be permanent in `sql_mode = ''`. This way MySQL will throw an error if an incorrect type is used. 
Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html for more details

Answer (score 1):

Like any DBMS, it does the implicit conversion.

For other type, according to the MySQL documentation, you have to use the convert/cast function
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html

Here is an example from SO:
[Convert text into number in MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960620/convert-text-into-number-in-mysql-query)

Comment: Postgres does not do implicit conversion when doing SELECT, and even when it does '1abc' != 1, so "any" is too broad when considering OP