# MySQL Query Anomaly

Tags: mysql

i faced a unique problem by accident

But before that i want to show you a table structure

td_category

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  category_id |  category_title  |  category_slug  |  p_cid          |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
|      1       |   Shirts         |   1-Shirts      |     0           |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
|      2       |   Jeans          |   2-Jeans       |     0           |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Now,

```
category_id is INT and auto-increment value
category_title is VARCHAR
category_slug is VARCHAR
```

Now what i amdoing is that, by mistake i wrote a query

```
SELECT * FROM td_category WHERE category_id = '2-Jeans'
```

and instead of giving me any error it displayed the 2nd tuple

Isn't it supposed to throw an error??

please can anybody clarify?

Comment: First guess is that '2-Jeans' will be casted to an int wich results in 2

Answer (score 1):

mysql performs implicit conversion for `int` datatype due to which '2-Jeans' is treated as 2-0 (since Jeans is not an int type and is defaulted to 0 for compatibility as described in the docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html))

Hence the final query as the parser interprets is as below:

```
SELECT * FROM td_category WHERE category_id = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will take id as `2` which is your first character and display second record

```
SELECT * FROM td_category WHERE category_id = '2-Jeans'
```

Try this query which will return first record

```
SELECT * FROM td_category WHERE category_id = '1-Jeans'
```

`2-jeans` is treated as `2` so return second record and `1-jeans` is treated as `1` so return first record.

Check [**Manual**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html) for auto casting in mysql.

Comment: Check this post may helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762075/mysql-automatically-cast-convert-a-string-to-a-number