# MySQL returns wrong results on search by id

Tags: mysql

I am having a simple table users with 'userid' and 'username' fields. Please check commands as follow:

```
Select * from users where userid = '5'; --returns me 1 result - Right

Select * from users where userid = '5 shiv'; --returns me 1 result - Wrong
```

Why second query still returns me one result. What could be the problem? Is this a problem with the engine or MySQL itself?

Comment: Share your table data and results.

Comment: This is a simple table with 'latin1_swedish_ci' collation

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762075/mysql-automatically-cast-convert-a-string-to-a-number

Comment: why downvote? Is it irrelevant question?

Comment: @dirtyhandsphp Probably because you haven't included the details, or done any more work yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that MySQL is doing an implicit conversion from the string to an int when doing the comparison. For example :

```
SELECT * FROM cloths WHERE id = "5 shiv"
```

making the conversion explicit, this is what MySQL is doing:

```
SELECT * FROM cloths WHERE id = CAST("5 shiv" as int)
```

Instead, what you want to do is cast the id to a string, and compare that way. The solution is simply to:

```
SELECT * FROM cloths WHERE CAST (id as varchar(10)) = "5 shiv"
```

You can also check by Refer the link:
[Doc link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89760/prevent-mysql-from-mangling-queries-by-casting-string-to-int)

Comment: why 2 answers ? And why do you copy `as it is` from the Link?

Comment: so that user can understand better

Comment: If you want to copy answer **`As It Is`** , Just Give link in Comment just below the Question as you are not adding anything else to the Readymade answer.

Comment: Please consider modifying answer as per OP's Query.

Answer (score 0):

`'5 shiv'` evaluates to 5 and skips your String part after 5.And you have record with userid as 5.

**Edit : Cast your expression to varchar**

```
Select * from users where CAST (userid as varchar(10)) = '5 shiv';
```

**[Refer here for more](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89760/prevent-mysql-from-mangling-queries-by-casting-string-to-int)**

Comment: Can you expand and explain why it would behave like that ? And ideally provide a reference ?

Comment: It behaves like that because you are telling it to compare a string to an integer :)