# Why "WHERE LIKE 'A%'='A%';" search result is false for 'A'?

Tags: mysql

There is a search box I've been testing using a blind sql injection technique.

When I want to get posts which include 'A', I just submit letter `A` in the search box. However, to get all the posts, I wanted to make the `WHERE LIKE` clause true.

So I post `A%'='A` to make the value true. I expected `SELECT * FROM list WHERE title LIKE 'A%'='A%';`. But it shows all the posts except the ones that include letter 'A'. Likewise, when I post `A%'! =' A`, I get the results that include `'A'`.

I don't know why this happens.

Comment: `WHERE title LIKE 'A%'` and not `WHERE title LIKE 'A%'='A%'`

Comment: I know.. But I just curious why this happens when send 'A%'='A%' query.

Comment: No.. I checked it before. when I test it, I receive all rows not include 'A'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query obviously does not make much sense, but MySQL will make its best effort to obey your request by using [autocast](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) to make sense of it.

First it will evaluate `title LIKE 'A%'`. This returns a truthy/falsy value, which for MySQL is `1` or `0` (an integer).

Next, you compel MySQL to compare this integer to `'A%'`. MySQL will try to comply to that request, and convert this string into [a 0 for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21762572).

So `LIKE 'A%'='A%'` will end up to be the same as

```
where (title LIKE 'A%') = 0
```

which is the same as

```
where not (title LIKE 'A%')
```

returning all titles that do not start with an `A`.

Similarly, `LIKE 'A%'!='A%'` will become

```
where (title LIKE 'A%') != 0
```

which is the same as

```
where (title LIKE 'A%')
```

so you get all titles that *do* start with an `A`.

Don't forget to tell the owner of that checkbox to [always parametrize your inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24988867).