# MySQL where in integer vs. where in string

Tags: mysql, database

Example Table

- Create table
- Insert records

SQL

```
-- create table
CREATE TABLE tests (id int AUTO_INCREMENT, foo varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY (id));
-- Insert records
INSERT INTO tests (foo) VALUES ('36'), ('36A'), ('36B'), ('36C'), ('baz');
```

Run:

```
SELECT * FROM tests where foo in ('36');
```

Result:

```
+----+------+
| id | foo  |
+----+------+
|  1 | 36   |
+----+------+
```

Then run: `SELECT * FROM tests where foo in (36);`

Result:

```
+----+------+
| id | foo  |
+----+------+
|  1 | 36   |
|  2 | 36A  |
|  3 | 36B  |
|  4 | 36C  |
+----+------+
```

#### Question

1. Why does passing `36` (as integer) not return the one identical record as passing `'36'` (as string) does?
2. Passing `3` results in an empty set. So I don't quite understand the logic.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21762075/4256677)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, there's a sort of implicit conversion between numbers and strings.

If you do a comparison between an integer and string, the string is converted to an integer. To convert a string to an integer, MySQL reads the leading numeric digits and ignores the rest. So `'36A'` has an integer value `36`. `'36B'` also has an integer value `36`. If there are no leading digits in the string, the integer value defaults to 0.

In your case, you compare the string values on a few rows to the integer `36`, which means it converts each string value to the numeric portion first.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html