# mysql using where in a query with number ignores trailing chars

Tags: mysql, mariadb

This is probably server settings but if I have a table with column ID: 
ID
12000

and I run this query

```
Select * from myTable where ID = "12000"
```

I get the row. 
My problem is that if I run

```
Select * from myTable where ID = "12000anystring"
```

returns the same row....

Can I force the server not to allow it.
(happens both in mysql and mariadb)

Comment: Please share the table structure and sample data, such that this question contains a reproducable example of that problem

Comment: Additionally, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762075/mysql-automatically-cast-convert-a-string-to-a-number